# "No matching benchmarks" when using JMH Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, jmh

The title says it, JMH plugin can't find any benchmarks even though the `./src/main/java` contains a class with a method annotated with `Benchmark`. Here's `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("me.champeau.jmh") version "0.7.0"
}

jmh {
    includes.set(listOf(".*"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:1.36")
    implementation("org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:1.36")
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `me.champeau.jmh` Gradle plugin adds its own source set with `src/main/jmh` as the source directory. It expects benchmark code to be there, not `src/main/java`.

Comment: yep, looks like it